# What plant did this root come from?

Tags: identification, roots

This may be a long shot, but I've got a very large (1.5 inch diameter) root running along the side of my house.  There is ivy, bamboo and lilac growing above it.  There is a 20 foot magnolia about 20 feet away.  There is a 50 foot Red Maple about 40 feet away.  Or is it something else entirely?  The roots seem very distinctive to me, so I have hope.[image]

Any help appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't identify it by appearance, but by the layout, it's probably the magnolia.  It doesn't look like maple to me, and it's really far to be that big.  I don't believe either lilac or bamboo would get this big, and from pictures it doesn't look like bamboo anyway.

Magnolia roots are supposed to be relatively soft and "ropy".

If your lilac is really huge and old, it *might* be that, I suppose.